# How to merge 1D & 2D tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

How to merge 1D & 2D tuples in Python?

So given two lists

```
heights = (   165,     152,     145,    174)
pos_2D  = ( (2,3), (32,52), (73,11), (43,97) )
```

I would like to so something like

```
pos_3D = merge(heights, pos_2D)
```

where

```
pos_3D = ( (2,3,165), (32,52,152), (73,11,145), (43,97,174) )
```

Whats the pythonic way to do this?

Comment: just make new tuple for the both. or use `zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `zip`

```
zip(heights,*zip(*pos_2D))

>>>[(165, 2, 3), (152, 32, 52), (145, 73, 11), (174, 43, 97)]
```

or if you want `tuple`

```
tuple(zip(heights,*zip(*pos_2D)))
>>>((165, 2, 3), (152, 32, 52), (145, 73, 11), (174, 43, 97))
```

`zip` makes list of tuples out of the two arguments and `zip(*_)` coverts the tuples back to individual arguments (think of it like unzip).

---

**Explanation on the code.**

```
heights = (   165,     152,     145,    174)
pos_2D  = ( (2,3), (32,52), (73,11), (43,97) )
```

With second tuple `pos_2D` we can unzip it to individual arguments as

```
pos_2D_unzipped = zip(*pos_2D)
print pos_2D_unzipped
>> [(2, 32, 73, 43), (3, 52, 11, 97)]
```

now we can use this to zip `heights` and `pos_2D_unzipped` together to get what you want.

for that we can do something like `zip(heights, pos_2D_unzipped)` but that only zips first 2 elements of zip with the two long tuples of `pos_2D_unzipped`.

```
zip(heights, pos_2D_unzipped)
[(165, (2, 32, 73, 43)), (152, (3, 52, 11, 97))]
```

What you really need to do is : provide `zip` with three arguments, 1. `heights`, 2. first element of `pos_2D_unzipped` and 3. second element of `pos_2D_unzipped`

so you could do something like :

```
zip(heights, pos_2D_unzipped[0],pos_2D_unzipped[1])
>>[(165, 2, 3), (152, 32, 52), (145, 73, 11), (174, 43, 97)]
```

Which works! But you can do something quicker. `pos_2D_unzipped` is a list of two elements (which are the long tuples), it would be great if you can give each element of list directly to the `zip`. And this is exactly what `*pos_2D_unzipped` does in side the `zip(__)`. It opens the list into individual arguments for the function.

thus, now you can do,

```
zip(heights, *pos_2D_unzipped)
>>[(165, 2, 3), (152, 32, 52), (145, 73, 11), (174, 43, 97)]
```

And even better, now you can compress the two steps of unzipping `pos_2D` and zipping the `heights` and `pos_2D_unzipped` into single step.

`zip(heights,*zip(*pos_2D))`

Comment: Could you explain how your first example works? Looks slightly magical (from a beginners perspective). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's very helpful. It make more sense.

Comment: That's very helpful. It make more sense. So first you break up the the 2D list into two tuples containing the first number x's, and y's. Then the *pos_2D_unzipped allows us to pass the x's & y's to the individually to the next zip function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip)

**Ex:**

```
heights = (   165,     152,     145,    174)
pos_2D  = ( (2,3), (32,52), (73,11), (43,97) )

print(tuple(j + (i,) for i, j in zip(heights, pos_2D)) )
```

**Output:**

```
((2, 3, 165), (32, 52, 152), (73, 11, 145), (43, 97, 174))
```

Comment: the list conversions seem unnecessary `tuple(j + (i,) for i, j in zip(heights, pos_2D))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly 1D or 2D. The first is just a tuple of integers, and the second a tuple of tuples. So, you just iterate over them in parallel (using zip) and create a new tuple element for each pair of elements

```
result = tuple( (*pos, h) for pos, h in zip(pos2D, heights))
```

Comment: That's just what I'm looking for :) Something simple and all in one line! Cool :) Thanks blue_note :)